# How to set the default cookie value in global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like to create a cookie and set a default value to it, for each user who visits the website. The cookie is to start the site in English language and later user can change the language to his preference.

I am doing this in global.asax

```
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("Language"); 
        myCookie.Value = "EN";
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

I tried to use the above code in following events,

```
Application_Start
Application_BeginRequest
Session_Start
```

In all the three events above, sets the cookie value to "EN" for every page load. Which should not be the case. When user selects some other language, the language must be set to HttpCookie("Language").

Answer (score 2):

you should first check if the cookie as not already been defined.. is it already set you have no need to set it again.. and when the user chooses a new language, then and only then you should redefine it... the general algorithm, and order of operations goes like this

> - if user is changing language
>
>   - change the language of the application to the chosen
>   - save it to cookie
> - else if the previous setting as been preserved in cookie
>
>   - change the language of the application to the preserved
> - else then is new visit
>
>   - change the language of the application to the default
>   - set cookie to the default

this should be evaluated in each request.. as the user may change language at any page..
so the proper event to place the code should be is the `Application_BeginRequest`

here is your code.. I am saving the language parameter in the `CurrentUICulture` so not only can it be queried in any place in the application, but the framework also uses it to customize the formats.. also I assume the user can pass a parameter named `lang` that contains the language that he desires..

```cs
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //if user is changing language
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request["lang"]))
    {
        String sLang =  HttpContext.Current.Request["lang"] as String;
        //change the language of the application to the chosen
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(sLang);
        //save it to cookie
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("Language"); 
        myCookie.Value = sLang;
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
    }
    //setting as been preserved in cookie
    else if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Language"])
    {
        //change the language of the application to the preserved
        String sLang =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["lang"].value as String;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(sLang);
    }
    else//new visit
    {
        //change the language of the application to the default
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
        //set cookie to the default
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("Language"); 
        myCookie.Value = "en-us";
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write code to update cookie value to what user has selected. When you say, "When user selects some other language", wherever that is, you need to retrieve that cookie from collection, update the cookie value there. Only then it can be work the way you need it to .